# Filter out some input with GREP

Tags: linux, grep, input-filtering

Echo "Hello everybody!"

I need to check whether the input argument of a linux script does comply with my security needs. It should contain only a-z characters, 0-9 digits, some spaces and the "+" sign. Eg.: "for 3 minutes do r51+r11"

This didn't worked for me:

```
if grep -v '[0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+ ]' /tmp/input; then
  echo "THIS DOES NOT COMPLY!";
fi
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling grep:

```
Show me every line that does not contain [0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+ ]
```

Which would only show you lines that contains neither of the characters above. So a line only containing other characters, like `()` would match, but `asdf()` would not match.

Try instead to have grep showing you every line that *contains* charachter **not** in the list above:

```
if grep '[^0-9A-Za-z+ ]' file; then
```

If you find something that's not a number or a letter or a plus, then.

Comment: Great. Remember to check the checkmark on one of the answers so others can see that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test the entire row (assuming there is only one row in /tmp/input), not just whether a single character anywhere matches, so you need to anchor it to the start end end of the row. Try this regexp:

`^[0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+ ]*$`

Note that you can shorten this using ranges:

`^[0-9a-z+ ]*$`